# Get value from a list and work with it

Tags: c#, list, socks

I am trying to build an application sends emails by socks, messages will be sent per message if the first message is sent through a socks, the second should use a different socks, what I do in my application if I as I Recuper the information from a txt file and I add to list :

```
try
{
    SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");

    var list = new List<string>();
    var input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\New folder\SendMail6\socks-list.txt");
    var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
         string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
         string port = match.Groups[2].Value;
         list.Add(ip);
         list.Add(port);
    }
    foreach (string ip in list)
    {

    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

what I want that

```
oServer.SocksProxyServer = "37.187.118.174";
oServer.SocksProxyPort = 14115;
```

takes the values from the list I completed by ip values and port, and

if the first mail is sent by an ip the second mail is use another ip in list dont send tow email which follow by same ip

Thanks

Comment: _"if an IP is, unwanted in the first, we have used the second in the second Message"_  is unclear. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Maybe if we had some example conrent of socks-list.txt too ?

Comment: if the first mail is sent by an ip the second mail is use another ip in list dont send tow email  which follow by same ip

Comment: You mean you want a list of IPs to cycle round?

Comment: BugFinder 104.131.163.123:2541
104.131.178.167:2541

Comment: BugFinder yes that what i want , sorry for my bad english

Comment: So, make a stack of valid IPs and ports, and take one, and then add it to the bottom on use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a class for IP and Port

```
public class IpAndPort
{
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
}
```

Now use [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

//------
var ips =  new ConcurrentBag<IpAndPort>();
var input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\New folder\SendMail6\socks-list.txt");
var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
{
     string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
     string port = match.Groups[2].Value;
     if(ips.Any(x => x.IpAddress.Trim() == ip.Trim()))
         continue; 
     ips.Add(new IpAndPort { IpAddress = ip, Port = port});
}
```

Now send message by taking values from ConcurrentBag

```
while (!ips.IsEmpty)
{
     IpAndPort ipAndPort;
     if (!ips.TryTake(out ipAndPort)) continue;
     try
     {
           //code here to send message using below IP and Port
           var ip = ipAndPort.IpAddress;
           var port = ipAndPort.Port;
           /----
           oServer = new SmtpServer("");
           oServer.SocksProxyServer = ip;
           oServer.SocksProxyPort = port;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: i want to affect the value var ip and var port to  oServer.SocksProxyServer = "37.187.118.174";
oServer.SocksProxyPort = 14115;

Comment: @CatSteven So whats the problem?

Comment: @CatSteven What do you want now?

Comment: the ip is the same , always he take the first ip in the txt file

Comment: @CatSteven Where you want to get IP and Port? Show your code.

Comment: @CatSteven It is not possible in ConcurrentBag unless your file has duplicate values

Comment: @CatSteven Are you adding the IPs into file unique. I think file gives you duplicate IPs. Are you sure?

Comment: i think that the problem is whene i affect the ip and the port to oServer.SocksProxyServer = ip;
           oServer.SocksProxyPort = port;

Comment: @CatSteven I have added a condition into the loop where we adding IP and Port to `ConcurrentBag` which not allow the code to add duplicate IP. Please try it and let me know

Comment: @CatSteven No, `ConcurrentBag` will always give you unique item. When we take one item from `ConcurrentBag` then it will no more available in next iteration.

Comment: it does not work, I think the problem comes from : oServer.SocksProxyServer = ip;
                        oServer.SocksProxyPort = port; normally it should come after SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");

Comment: what we need to do recovered the ip and port values from the loop and has affected  oServer.SocksProxyServer, and  oServer.SocksProxyPort

Comment: @CatSteven You mean when we assign ip first time in `oServer.SocksProxyServer = ip;` and then different ip in second time but `SocksProxyServer` does not take new one, its use old one, right?

Comment: @CatSteven Where you are creating the object `oServer`?

Comment: SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");

Comment: SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");
                oServer.SocksProxyServer = ip;
                oServer.SocksProxyPort = port; normally the code will be like this

Comment: Try to add `SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");` in loop where we taking IP from `ConcurrentBag` and then assign IP

Comment: @CatSteven I have edited my answer, `oServer = new SmtpServer("");` added before assigning new IP. Check it

Comment: @CatSteven Did you update my edit? Initialize as `oServer = new SmtpServer("");`

Comment: @CatSteven Can you show complete code? Or [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and put your query that why server does not change IP once he took?

Comment: @CatSteven By the way I gave you actual answer to your original question. You should ask another question for other problem.

Comment: do you have a skybe account ?

Comment: @CatSteven Yes I have but I can't speak English fluently.

Comment: me too im not professionel in english i watch you my code directly

Comment: if they not have problem

Comment: 300 583 829      pass:3jc87w